# How to execute (run) arquillian tests (feature methods in terms of spock) from command line (cli)?

Tags: java, integration-testing, spock, jboss-arquillian

I am using arquillian with jboss AS all in eclipse IDE . 
I wand to execute arquillian tests from command line .
As arquillian first invokes methods annotated with @deployment then it executes tests.
OR
Any solution to integrate with jenkins.

Comment: No, I am using Sputnik spockRunner.

Comment: :-) So you are using JUnit. The Arquillian class SpockTestRunner is a wrapper for a 'org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik' which in turn extends 'org.junit.runner.Runner'. Nevertheless ... running such a test setup via command line seems to be a bit complicated. The template command would be "java -cp <class path> <TestRunnerClass>" I assume, the test runner class must still be 'org.junit.runner.JUnitCore'. The main method expects the test classes as arguments. The before mentioned class path must contain all libraries. This is the tricky part: all Arquillian libs, and all other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to execute tests is via build tools (i-e, Gradle ,Maven , ant , etc).
Then execute gradle tasks via jenkins.